# Speed up calculations with arrays/dictionaries

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a large macro which calculates diverse things for my job. I work in a contact center.

Firstly it writes people and forecast data. With this calculates if there are more/less people than it should (depending on the forecast). After this calculation Uses it to calculate the break time for everyone `CalculadoraAux`.

Once this is all done, the calculation starts(and is the slow block of the code). First for department and then for department and city(this last depends on the department and the number of people working on each city to distribuite things). It calculates for half hours and then 4 totals, grand total, morning, afternoon and night.

Hope I've explained myself kind of clearly, but I can answer anything you need to help me speed up this code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Recalcular(Reforecast As Boolean)

    Dim arrAgentes As Variant, wsTD As Worksheet, Comprueba As Boolean, Col As Integer, ColIAux, ColFAux, Reductores As Single, _
    LastRow As Long, x As Long, i As Long, C As Range, y As Long, B As Byte, ColI, ColF, wsP As Worksheet, _
    wsObj As Worksheet, arrKPI As Variant, arrKPI2 As Variant, A As Long, arrDescansos, _
    DictModoDia As Scripting.Dictionary, arrPronosticos, wsPron As Worksheet, wsDescanso As Worksheet, STRUnion As String
    Dim Contador

    '=========================FROM HERE============================='
    Dim DictPronosticos As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim DictHojaPronosticos As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim DictModosDias As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set DictPronosticos = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set DictModos = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set DictModoDia = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set DictHojaPronosticos = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set DictModosDias = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Programaciones")
    Set wsP = wb.Sheets("Servicio")
    Set wsObj = wb.Sheets("Objetivos")
    Set wsPron = wb.Sheets("Pronosticos")
    If Reforecast Then Set wsPron = wb.Sheets("PronosticosReforecast")
    With ws
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("E5:BD" & i).ClearContents
    End With
    Call CrearTablaAgentes 'PivotTable Creation
    Set wsTD = wb.Sheets("TablaProgramados")
    LastRow = wsTD.Cells(wsTD.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arrAgentes = wsTD.Range("A2:BC" & LastRow).Value 'Store PivotTable into array

    'Dictionary
    For i = LBound(arrAgentes) To UBound(arrAgentes)
        If arrAgentes(i, 2) = vbNullString Then
        ElseIf Not arrAgentes(i, 3) = vbNullString Then
            STRUnion = Application.Proper(arrAgentes(i, 3)) & arrAgentes(i, 1) & arrAgentes(i, 2) & "1.Presentes Programados"
            DictModosDias.Add STRUnion, i
        Else
            STRUnion = "ALL" & arrAgentes(i, 1) & Mid(arrAgentes(i, 2), 7, Len(arrAgentes(i, 2))) & "1.Presentes Programados"
            DictModosDias.Add STRUnion, i
        End If
    Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsTD.Delete

    ColI = Array(5, 21, 37, 5)
    ColF = Array(52, 36, 52, 20)
    ColIAux = Array(13, 109, 205, 13)
    ColFAux = Array(300, 204, 300, 108)

    'Dictionary to know positions on some data
    For Each C In wsP.Range("C35", wsP.Range("C35").End(xlDown))
        If C.Font.Color = 49407 Then
            DictPronosticos.Add C.Value, 1
        End If
    Next C

    'Goal Data
    With wsObj
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Rows(LastRow & ":1000").Delete
        arrObjetivos = wsObj.UsedRange.Value
    End With

    'Dictionary to know where the goal positions are
    For i = 2 To UBound(arrObjetivos)
        DictModos.Add arrObjetivos(i, 2), i
    Next i

    'Main data to be calculated
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        arrMatriz = .Range("A5:BD" & LastRow).Value
    End With

    'Dictionary to know the position of each group
    Set DictKPIModoDia = New Scripting.Dictionary
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrMatriz)
        DictKPIModoDia.Add arrMatriz(i, 1) & arrMatriz(i, 2) & arrMatriz(i, 3) & arrMatriz(i, 4), i
    Next i

    'Data
    arrPronosticos = wsPron.UsedRange.Value

    'Dictionary to know the position of each group
    For i = 2 To UBound(arrPronosticos)
        DictHojaPronosticos.Add arrPronosticos(i, 1) & arrPronosticos(i, 2) & arrPronosticos(i, 3) & arrPronosticos(i, 4), i
    Next i

    Dim Centro As String, Modo As String, Fecha As Date, KPI As String, Centros, Multiplicador As Single, CentroFuncion As String
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrMatriz, 1)
        'Rellenamos los pronósticos
        Centro = arrMatriz(i, 1)
        Modo = arrMatriz(i, 3)
        Fecha = CDate(arrMatriz(i, 2))
        KPI = arrMatriz(i, 4)
        If DictPronosticos.Exists(KPI) Then
            For A = 5 To 56
                If DictHojaPronosticos.Exists(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI) Then
                    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI), A) = arrPronosticos(DictHojaPronosticos(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI), A)
                Else
                    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI), A) = vbNullString
                End If
            Next A
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrMatriz, 1)
        Centro = arrMatriz(i, 1)
        Modo = arrMatriz(i, 3)
        Fecha = CDate(arrMatriz(i, 2))
        KPI = arrMatriz(i, 4)
        If KPI = "1.Presentes Programados" Then
            STRUnion = Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI
            For A = 5 To 56
                On Error Resume Next
                arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI), A) = arrAgentes(DictModosDias(STRUnion), A - 1)
                If arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI), A) = 0 Then arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI), A) = vbNullString
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next A
        ElseIf KPI = "2.Efectivos" Then
            For A = 5 To 52
                arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI), A) = Formulas(Fecha, Modo, KPI, A, i, arrDescansos, _
                DictModoDia, Centro)
                If arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI), A) = 0 Then arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI), A) = vbNullString
            Next A
            For A = 53 To 56
                ReDim Contador(ColI(A - 53) To ColF(A - 53)) As Double
                On Error Resume Next
                For Col = LBound(Contador) To UBound(Contador)
                    Contador(Col) = arrMatriz(i, Col)
                Next Col
                On Error GoTo 0
                arrMatriz(i, A) = Application.Sum(Contador) / 2
                If arrMatriz(i, A) = 0 Then arrMatriz(i, A) = vbNullString
            Next A
        ElseIf KPI = "94.Sobre/Infra" Then
            For A = 5 To 56
                arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI), A) = Formulas(Fecha, Modo, KPI, A, i, arrDescansos, _
                DictModoDia, Centro)
            Next A
        End If
    Next i

    ws.Range("A5:BD" & UBound(arrMatriz) + 4) = arrMatriz
    Debug.Print Timer & "aux"
    Outputs.CalculadoraAux
    Debug.Print Timer & "aux"
    '=========================TO HERE=============================' Fast Enough

    '=========================FROM HERE============================='
    wb.Sheets("Mapa Turnos").AutoFilterMode = False
    Set wsDescanso = wb.Sheets("Calculadora AUX")
    arrDescansos = wsDescanso.UsedRange.Value
    wsDescanso.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    For i = 2 To UBound(arrDescansos)
        If Not DictModoDia.Exists(arrDescansos(i, 1) & arrDescansos(i, 3)) Then
            DictModoDia.Add arrDescansos(i, 1) & arrDescansos(i, 3), i
        Else
            DictModoDia(arrDescansos(i, 1) & arrDescansos(i, 3)) = DictModoDia(arrDescansos(i, 1) & arrDescansos(i, 3)) & ", " & i
        End If
    Next i
    Dim SplitCentros, arrPorcentaje, m As Long, CentroCC As String, DictPorcentajeCentros As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set DictPorcentajeCentros = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Erase Contador

    'Calculate KPIs but the ones already calculated
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrMatriz, 1)
        Centro = arrMatriz(i, 1)
        Modo = arrMatriz(i, 3)
        Fecha = CDate(arrMatriz(i, 2))
        KPI = arrMatriz(i, 4)
        If Centro <> "ALL" And KPI = "1.Presentes Programados" Then  'aquí calculamos directamente las capacidades y el % según centro para llamadas y req
            For A = 5 To 56
                If arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "5.Pronóstico"), A) = 0 And Not A = 56 Then GoTo SiguienteCC
                SplitCentros = Split(wb.Sheets("Servicio").Cells.Find(Modo).Offset(0, 1), "/")
                ReDim arrPorcentaje(0 To UBound(SplitCentros))
                For m = 0 To UBound(SplitCentros) 'Rellenamos Efectivos Finales para poder hacer el cálculo a todos
                    CentroCC = SplitCentros(m)
                    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(CentroCC & Fecha & Modo & "21.Descansos Finales"), A) = _
                        Formulas(Fecha, Modo, "21.Descansos Finales", A, i, arrDescansos, DictModoDia, CentroCC)
                    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(CentroCC & Fecha & Modo & "22.Efectivos Finales"), A) = _
                        Formulas(Fecha, Modo, "22.Efectivos Finales", A, i, arrDescansos, DictModoDia, CentroCC)
                Next m
                For m = 0 To UBound(SplitCentros)
                    On Error Resume Next
                    arrPorcentaje(m) = _
                    (arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(SplitCentros(m) & Fecha & Modo & "22.Efectivos Finales"), A) * 1800) / _
                    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(SplitCentros(m) & Fecha & Modo & "6.TMO"), A)
                    DictPorcentajeCentros.Add SplitCentros(m), m
                    On Error GoTo 0
                Next m
                'Porcentaje a aplicar
                On Error Resume Next
                Multiplicador = 0
                Multiplicador = arrPorcentaje(DictPorcentajeCentros(Centro)) / Application.Sum(arrPorcentaje)
                DictPorcentajeCentros.RemoveAll
                'Call Capacity
                arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "95.Call Capacity"), A) = _
                    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia("ALL" & Fecha & Modo & "95.Call Capacity"), A) * Multiplicador
                'Pronóstico
                arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "5.Pronóstico"), A) = Multiplicador * _
                    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia("ALL" & Fecha & Modo & "5.Pronóstico"), A)
                'Call Capacity ajustado
                If arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "95.Call Capacity"), A) > _
                arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "5.Pronóstico"), A) Then
                    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "96.Call Capacity ajustado curva"), A) = _
                    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "5.Pronóstico"), A)
                Else
                    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "96.Call Capacity ajustado curva"), A) = _
                    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "95.Call Capacity"), A)
                End If
                'Requeridos
                arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "92.Requeridos"), A) = Multiplicador * _
                    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia("ALL" & Fecha & Modo & "92.Requeridos"), A)
                'NDA

                arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "3.NA"), A) = Multiplicador * _
                    (arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia("ALL" & Fecha & Modo & "3.NA"), A) * _
                    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia("ALL" & Fecha & Modo & "5.Pronóstico"), A)) / arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "5.Pronóstico"), A)
                'NDS
                arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "4.SL"), A) = Multiplicador * _
                    (arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia("ALL" & Fecha & Modo & "4.SL"), A) * _
                    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia("ALL" & Fecha & Modo & "5.Pronóstico"), A)) / arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "5.Pronóstico"), A)
                'Descubierto
                If arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "5.Pronóstico"), A) > 0 And _
                    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "22.Efectivos Finales"), A) = 0 Then _
                        arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "93.Descubierto"), A) = "SI"
                'Sobre/Infra
                On Error Resume Next
                arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "94.Sobre/Infra"), A) = _
                    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "22.Efectivos Finales"), A) - _
                        arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "92.Requeridos"), A)
                'Occupancy
                If A < 53 Then
                    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "97.Occ"), A) = _
                        (arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "5.Pronóstico"), A) * _
                        arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "6.TMO"), A)) / _
                        (arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "22.Efectivos Finales"), A) * 1800)
                    If arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "97.Occ"), A) > 1 Then _
                        arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "97.Occ"), A) = 1 'si el occupancy es mayor que 1
                ElseIf A = 56 Then
                    KPI = "97.Occ"
                    GoTo Totales:
                End If
SiguienteCC:
            Next A
        End If
        If KPI = "92.Requeridos" Or KPI = "5.Pronóstico" Or DictPronosticos.Exists(KPI) Then GoTo SiguienteKPI
        If KPI = "1.Presentes Programados" Or KPI = "2.Efectivos" Or Centro = "ALL" And KPI = "94.Sobre/Infra" Then GoTo SiguienteKPI
        If Centro <> "ALL" And Not arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "5.Pronóstico"), 53) = 0 Then GoTo SiguienteKPI
        For A = 5 To 52
            arrMatriz(i, A) = Formulas(Fecha, Modo, KPI, A, i, arrDescansos, DictModoDia, Centro)
        Next A
Totales:
        'Totals
        For A = 53 To 56
            Select Case KPI
                Case "93.Descubierto", "94.Sobre/Infra", "96.Call Capacity ajustado curva"
                    arrMatriz(i, A) = Formulas(Fecha, Modo, KPI, A, i, arrDescansos, DictModoDia, Centro)
                Case "3.NA", "4.SL", "97.Occ"
                    ReDim arrKPI(ColI(A - 53) To ColF(A - 53))
                    ReDim arrKPI2(ColI(A - 53) To ColF(A - 53))
                    For Col = ColI(A - 53) To ColF(A - 53)
                        arrKPI2(Col) = arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "5.Pronóstico"), Col)
                        arrKPI(Col) = arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI), Col)
                    Next Col
                    On Error Resume Next
                    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI), A) = Application.SumProduct(arrKPI, arrKPI2) / Application.Sum(arrKPI2)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    Erase arrKPI
                    Erase arrKPI2
                    If arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI), A) > 0 And arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI), A) > 1 And Not KPI = "97.Occ" Then arrMatriz(i, A) = 1
                Case "21.Descansos Finales"
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Reductores = arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "7.Formación"), A) + _
                        arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "9.Ausencias no programadas"), A) + _
                        arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "91.Otros"), A)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    Contador = Split(DictModoDia(arrMatriz(i, 2) & arrMatriz(i, 3)), ", ")
                    If UBound(Contador) = -1 Then
                        arrMatriz(i, A) = 0
                        GoTo SiguienteKPI
                    End If
                    With wsDescanso
                        arrMatriz(i, A) = (Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(Contador(0), ColIAux(A - 53)), _
                        .Cells(Contador(UBound(Contador)), ColFAux(A - 53)))) * 60) / _
                            (Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(Contador(0), 7), .Cells(Contador(UBound(Contador)), 8))) * 3600)
                    End With
                    If arrMatriz(i, A) = 0 Then arrMatriz(i, A) = vbNullString
                Case "1.Presentes Programados", "2.Efectivos", "22.Efectivos Finales"
                    ReDim Contador(ColI(A - 53) To ColF(A - 53)) As Double
                    On Error Resume Next
                    For Col = LBound(Contador) To UBound(Contador)
                        Contador(Col) = arrMatriz(i, Col)
                    Next Col
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    arrMatriz(i, A) = Application.Sum(Contador) / 2
                Case Else
                    ReDim arrKPI(ColI(A - 53) To ColF(A - 53))
                    For Col = ColI(A - 53) To ColF(A - 53)
                        arrKPI(Col) = arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "95.Call Capacity"), Col)
                    Next Col
                    arrMatriz(i, A) = Application.Sum(arrKPI)
                    If arrMatriz(i, A) = 0 Then arrMatriz(i, A) = vbNullString
                    Erase arrKPI
            End Select
        Next A

SiguienteKPI:

    Next i

    '=========================TO HERE=============================' Very slow and time consuming.

    'Paste the array back to the worksheet
    With ws
        .Range("A5:BD" & UBound(arrMatriz) + 4) = arrMatriz
    End With

End Sub
```

External functions such as `CalculadoraAux` or `Formulas` don't have effect on the executing time.

PS: there might be variables not declared here, but they are global variables (When I first started this I didn't know that shouldn't happen...)

Edit: [Sample](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/20145eb8dc91fd2522b303a33c27d9c920190508150435/206b9a8879e04569b4d3493826297c8b20190508150435/e6ede9)  This will stay up for 7 days. This file takes about 57s to complete the calculation (is one of the fastest) before some changes it was taking 5-10 seconds which was the optimal time since the users click this button often.

Comment: Are there 2 separate code blocks included? I see `From Here` and `To Here` twice.

Comment: just to let you know where the process slows down. but its a single procedure.

Comment: Do you have any sample data you can provide that will work with your code above?

Comment: @PeterT  I uploaded a sample file the link is on my post.

Answer (score 1):

Performance could improve by merging these two loops into one (inside the `For A = 5 To 56` loop) and taking two of these `DictKPIModoDia` values to a variable (since they don't change inside the loop):

```
Dim upperBound as long
upperBound = UBound(SplitCentros)
For m = 0 To upperBound 'Rellenamos Efectivos Finales para poder hacer el cálculo a todos
    CentroCC = SplitCentros(m)
    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(CentroCC & Fecha & Modo & "21.Descansos Finales"), A) = _
        Formulas(Fecha, Modo, "21.Descansos Finales", A, i, arrDescansos, DictModoDia, CentroCC)
    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(CentroCC & Fecha & Modo & "22.Efectivos Finales"), A) = _
        Formulas(Fecha, Modo, "22.Efectivos Finales", A, i, arrDescansos, DictModoDia, CentroCC)
    'end of original first loop
    On Error Resume Next 'here it is better to check that the denominator arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(CentroCC & Fecha & Modo & "6.TMO"), A) <> 0 instead of resuming next. If you really need this resume next, place it before the loop.
    arrPorcentaje(m) = _
        (arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(CentroCC & Fecha & Modo & "22.Efectivos Finales"), A) * 1800) / arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(CentroCC & Fecha & Modo & "6.TMO"), A)
    DictPorcentajeCentros.Add CentroCC, m
    On Error GoTo 0 'You probably don't need this, specially if you check above calculation for zero in the denominator
    'end of original second loop
Next m
```

The other thing that might improve performance would be if you manage to incorporate this `Totales: For A = 53 To 56` loop *in your main A loop* so that you don't have to loop again. Something like this:

```
'Occupancy
If A < 53 Then
    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "97.Occ"), A) = _
                        (arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "5.Pronóstico"), A) * _
    arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "6.TMO"), A)) / _
                        (arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "22.Efectivos Finales"), A) * 1800)
    If arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "97.Occ"), A) > 1 Then _
                        arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "97.Occ"), A) = 1 'si el occupancy es mayor que 1
ElseIf A = 56 Then
    KPI = "97.Occ"
    'GoTo Totales: 'Commented out
Else '53 to 56
    'Here, the code to calculate totals from A=53 to 56, ideally a call to a function. Ex:
     CaculateKPI
End If
```

...

```
Public Sub CalculateKPI()
    Select Case KPI
        Case "93.Descubierto", "94.Sobre/Infra", "96.Call Capacity ajustado curva"
            arrMatriz(i, A) = Formulas(Fecha, Modo, KPI, A, i, arrDescansos, DictModoDia, Centro)
         Case "3.NA", "4.SL", "97.Occ"
            ReDim arrKPI(ColI(A - 53) To ColF(A - 53))
            ReDim arrKPI2(ColI(A - 53) To ColF(A - 53))
            For Col = ColI(A - 53) To ColF(A - 53)
                arrKPI2(Col) = arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "5.Pronóstico"), Col)
                arrKPI(Col) = arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI), Col)
             Next Col
             On Error Resume Next
             arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI), A) = Application.SumProduct(arrKPI, arrKPI2) / Application.Sum(arrKPI2)
             On Error GoTo 0
             Erase arrKPI
             Erase arrKPI2
             If arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI), A) > 0 And arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & KPI), A) > 1 And Not KPI = "97.Occ" Then arrMatriz(i, A) = 1
         Case "21.Descansos Finales"
             On Error Resume Next
             Reductores = arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "7.Formación"), A) + _
                        arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "9.Ausencias no programadas"), A) + _
             arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "91.Otros"), A)
             On Error GoTo 0
             Contador = Split(DictModoDia(arrMatriz(i, 2) & arrMatriz(i, 3)), ", ")
             If UBound(Contador) = -1 Then
             arrMatriz(i, A) = 0
             GoTo SiguienteKPI
         End If
         With wsDescanso
             arrMatriz(i, A) = (Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(Contador(0), ColIAux(A - 53)), _
                        .Cells(Contador(UBound(Contador)), ColFAux(A - 53)))) * 60) / _
             (Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(Contador(0), 7), .Cells(Contador(UBound(Contador)), 8))) * 3600)
         End With
         If arrMatriz(i, A) = 0 Then arrMatriz(i, A) = vbNullString
     Case "1.Presentes Programados", "2.Efectivos", "22.Efectivos Finales"
         ReDim Contador(ColI(A - 53) To ColF(A - 53)) As Double
         On Error Resume Next
         For Col = LBound(Contador) To UBound(Contador)
             Contador(Col) = arrMatriz(i, Col)
         Next Col
         On Error GoTo 0
         arrMatriz(i, A) = Application.Sum(Contador) / 2
      Case Else
         ReDim arrKPI(ColI(A - 53) To ColF(A - 53))
         For Col = ColI(A - 53) To ColF(A - 53)
             arrKPI(Col) = arrMatriz(DictKPIModoDia(Centro & Fecha & Modo & "95.Call Capacity"), Col)
         Next Col
         arrMatriz(i, A) = Application.Sum(arrKPI)
         If arrMatriz(i, A) = 0 Then arrMatriz(i, A) = vbNullString
            Erase arrKPI
      End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I uploaded a sample file, the link is on my post.